# Transactions in webflux with blocking spring data

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-transactions

Given: reactive system with webflux, traditional spring data with jdbc driver, how could I manage transactions in methods like:

```
Mono<TrxResponse> doTrx(){
return Mono.fromCallable(() -> parentRepository.save(parent))
                   .flatMap(parent()-> {
                    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> childRepository.save(child)})
                   .flatmap(resp -> {return new TrxResponse()}); 
}
```

Comment: Spring published a blog on transaction with webflux. It may be worth a read.
https://spring.io/blog/2019/05/16/reactive-transactions-with-spring

Comment: I'd also advise against using a blocking database driver and instead use a reactive one, like r2dbc, when you are working with reactive applications

Comment: Some experienced people strongly advised against r2dbc. As far as Im concerned, the driver still got unfixed bugs and is not production ready yet. My hopes are all about reactive hibernate + vert.x.

Comment: yes, there are alternates to r2dbc and I'd suggest to explore them all and choose the one that best fits your use case. R2DBC was just given as an example. Though I'd still suggest using a reactive database driver if you want to see the full benefits of reactive systems.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a separate transaction layer with blocking update methods to DB, like:

```
class TransactionRepo {

    private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;
    
    // save to DB method
    public Void saveObjects(Parent parent, Child child) {
        saveParent(parent);
        savechild(child);
    }
    
    // your reactive method 
    public Mono<Void> saveObjectsAsync(Parent parent, Child child) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> transactionTemplate.execute(transactionStatus -> 
            saveObjects(parent, child)));
    }
}
```